# VB .net datagridview properties via variable

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview, datagrid

This may be a weird question. Just out of curiosity asking it to learn/check if this can be really achieved or not?
Normally we can change the datagridview(name of the grid is **dgv**) properties like below

```
Prp_Value = 150
dgv.Columns(columnName).Width = Prp_Value
Prp_Value = “Header Text”
dgv.Columns(columnName).HeaderText = Prp_Value
Prp_Value = 0
dgv.Columns(columnName).DisplayIndex = Prp_Value
Prp_Value = True
dgv.Columns(columnName).Visible = Prp_Value
```

What I am checking here is that can we able to access the properties via variable (as something like below):

```
Dim Prp_Type as String 
Prp_Type = “Width”
Prp_Value = 150
dgv.Columns(columnName).&”’” Prp_Type &”’” =  Prp_Value
Prp_Type = “HeaderText”
Prp_Value = “Header Text”
dgv.Columns(columnName).&”’” Prp_Type &”’” =  Prp_Value
Prp_Type = “DisplayIndex”
Prp_Value = 0
dgv.Columns(columnName).&”’” Prp_Type &”’” =  Prp_Value
```

and so on, because trying to set the datagridview properties by reading the info from XML file.
Were xml file content like below (It may have some properties or not like below ex for **AutoSizeMode** [1st column no AutoSizeMode but for 2nd column its set as true])

```
      <Name>columnName</Name>
      <width>100</width>
      <Headertext>ID</Headertext>
      <DisplayIndex >0</DisplayIndex >
      <Visible >False</Visible>
    </column>
<column>
      <Name> columnName2 </Name>
      <width>102</width>
      <Headertext>ID</Headertext>
      <DisplayIndex >1</DisplayIndex>
      <Visible >True</Visible>
      <AutoSizeMode>True</AutoSizeMode>
</column>
```

So, let me know whether it is possible or not.

Thank you

Comment: Guessing you're after some sort of Macro substitution here and run time compiling.  While I wouldn't 100% say no, it's a world of hurt.  What you can do though is pass you column into a procedure that sets all the properties required

Comment: @Hursey Yes I am trying to manipulate / determine the datagridview property from the XML name tag (<Width> / <Headertext>), I am able to extract the tag name and its value by `childnodes name by [coverageTag.ChildNodes(Noofnodes).Name] and value 
 using inntertext by [coverageTag.ChildNodes(Noofnodes).InnerText]`. how do I assign or use the childnode name as the datagridview property? some thing like this `dgv.Columns(columnName).coverageTag.ChildNodes(Noofnodes).Name = coverageTag.ChildNodes(Noofnodes).InnerText` ?

Comment: @Hursey / All, Any Idea how to solve this issue please?

Comment: Hi all, Just want to know if this can be done or not? please provide your valuable feed back. Thanks

Comment: So the idea your after is how to serialise and deserialise a datagridview property set.  A large part of how this works is dependant on how the xml is generated.  Using the standard DVG control, there really is no way to do it out of the box, will with have to parse the xml manually and set the properties as any other control.  There are a number of 3rd party controls that will do this for you that may be worth researching